# How to run hadoop cluster balancer from gateway machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have written a script which checks Hadoop block report and if needed it runs hadoop balancer. I read  [this article about hdfs balancer design](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12368261/RebalanceDesign6.pdf) and it looks like we need to run HDFS balancer on separate machine so that it will not overload name node.

Please correct me if my this understanding is correct or not.

Now I have setup one separate node and installed Hadoop on it but this machine is not part of the cluster. Data node or task tracker daemons are not running on this machine.

When I run `hadoop balancer` command on this machine I get only following output:

```
$ hadoop balancer
Balancing took 135.0 milliseconds
$
```

I tried to execute `start-balancer.sh` script directly but I get similar output. Only variation is that this script writes that single line in its .out file.

When I executed `hadoop balancer` command on Name node I get following output:

```
ubuntu@master:~$ hadoop balancer
Time Stamp               Iteration#  Bytes Already Moved  Bytes Left To Move  Bytes Being Moved
14/11/19 06:14:03 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/20.232.273.15:50010
14/11/19 06:14:03 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/20.294.195.28:50010
14/11/19 06:14:03 INFO balancer.Balancer: 0 over utilized nodes:
14/11/19 06:14:03 INFO balancer.Balancer: 0 under utilized nodes:
The cluster is balanced. Exiting...
Balancing took 477.0 milliseconds
```

From this output it looks like balancer runs only on namenode. So my question is do we always need to run balancer on name node only? Or do we need to do some configuration to make this balancer run on gateway machines?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check if you cluster is balanced is to visit namenode web UI or goto hadoop dfsadmin -report for latest stats. Dont go with the time it has taken or log on console. Also it not best practice to run balancer on namenode and it should be run from a client node.